# Why connection timed out when recording in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I was recording script in Jmeter and got error like this:

`There is a problem with this website's security certificate`

[image]

then I click `Continue to this website (not recommended)`

and got connection timed out like this:

`java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method) at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) at java.net.`

Please help.

**UPDATED**

I should run jmeter using proxy due to proxy enabled in my area.

After running using proxy, I found new error SAML Authentication (https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-saml-sso-secured-websites)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure you add the JMeter Certificate Authority to your browser following this documentation:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder

> Installing the JMeter CA certificate for HTTPS recording

This file is generated in "**jmeter/bin/ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt**" when your start the recorder.